# Log4J MaxFileSize limit exceeding issue

Tags: log4j, java-ee-7

I'm using Log4j 1.2.16 in a java application.
I've set log4j.properties file with the following values.

```
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=5
```

The trouble is that, from time to time, the 20MB limit gets surpassed and I get huge files that can reach upto 200GB.

What I suspect is that the log writing process is getting max priority and writing a lot of data very fast and not letting the limit checking to be carried out until it's too late. Does that make any sense?

Could it be a Log4j bug? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

This should happen because in `rollOver()` method of `RollingFileAppender.java`, renaming of the current log file can fail.

For instance if you have opened the log file with another editor, LOG4J is not able to change the name.

Comment: ... especially if you're running on Windows